# jQuery SelectBox webkit (?) shadow

Tags: webkit, jquery-selectbox

I have jQuery SelectBox running to re-style a select menu at top-left here: https://washington-street-originals.myshopify.com -- but am still getting shadows in webkit... what gives?

Comment: Who knows? Please post some code.

Comment: This fixzed it: `outline:-webkit-focus-ring-color auto 0px; outline-color:-webkit-focus-ring-color; outline-style:auto; outline-width: 0px;`